# MySQL Column Value Auto Increment To be Unique Within a Specific Range

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Is it possible in MySQL to define an autoincrement column to be within a specific range while excluding a list of numbers?

For example, I am trying to find a way to define a column to be within `3000-4000` while excluding `3123-3200`, `3312-3400`.

I am using DBeaver to design a table.

Comment: Autoincrement columsn generally don't implement this contract.  Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: I want to define a port number for a socket communication in my database. It has to be unique, and autoincrement. It also shouldn't use the port numbers that are being used by the OS (the excluding list).

Comment: If an id has any meaning beyond the scope of the database, don't use the AI feature for its construction